# Compact USB only mixer

Tags: usb

I am looking for a pocket compact USB only mixer that has only USB inputs and one USB output.
After 3 hours of searching in Google, Amazon and other sites I found only analog ones.

- Some USB inputs should function as USB-hosts for devices like USB microphones.
- Some USB inputs should function as external digital sound card for devices like other computers or portable players.
- USB output should function as an external digital sound card for a computer.
- Audio information in digital form, without conversion to analog form, should be mixed in variable proportions using a digital adder/subtractor with knobs, and then sent to the USB-connected output device.

The idea is to use such a mixer when software mixing solutions aren't available, for example:

- when organizing an audio chat in Telegram from a mobile phone over USB-OTG with an ability to mix in an external audio source to microphone sound.
- or when some software/hardware manufacturer decides not to support some particular sound routing for particular devices.

Does it exist at all?

P.S. A second variant of that could be an USB device that is working with PC (Windows or MAC) only over a single USB cable, but is detected in the PC as two USB sound outputs and one USB audio input device, like explained here: https://musicianshq.com/how-does-a-usb-mixer-work/

Particularly I would like to use such a mixer with MacBook, Open Broadcaster Software, Desktop version of Telegram and Samson Meteor microphone. This microphone has a built-in USB-connected sound adapter to monitor the sound over headphones jack.

I should be able to:

- cast audio from USB microphone to Telegram
- cast video from MAC to Telegram
- monitor audio over sound adapter built in into the microphone

All three tasks were possible. What I couldn't achieve is to mix in an audio file with an output to both, Telegram and audio monitoring output of the microphone.

Comment: USB mixer? Like a USB hub?

Comment: Timinycricket, I updated the question in order to explain my vision.

Comment: I don’t think anything like that exists but have you tried creating an aggregate device on your Mac? If all three tasks were possible except you need an extra output to the microphone then that should be all you need.

Comment: Hi there - this isn't about Sound Design - I'll migrate to Hardware Recs. But I don't think such a product would. The price point it would need to be at to include all those things would take it into pro territory, where the problems you are facing don't exist.